# A question on matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$.

Is it true that ${\left\| A \right\|_2} = {\left( {\sum\limits_{i,j} {{{\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|}^2}} } \right)^{1/2}} = \mathop {\max {{\left\| {Ax} \right\|}_2}}\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} $

Comment: Try the identity matrix for $n> 1$

Comment: Maybe he means ${\left( {\sum\limits_{i,j} {\left| {a_{ij}} \right|^2} } \right)^{1/2}}$

Comment: @Matthias - I'm sorry, I edited this post.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true. It can be confusing because they are usually indicated with the same symbol.

One is the Frobenius norm
$$ \|A\|_F = \left(\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2 \right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger A)} = \left(\sum_i \sigma_i^2\right)^{1/2}, $$
where $\sigma_i^2$ are the eigenvalues of the positive matrix $A^\dagger A$.

The Frobenius norm is the Euclidean norm of the vector of the singular values $\sigma_i$ of $A$.

The other is the induced norm
$$ \|A\|_2 = \mathrm{sup}_{x\neq 0} \frac{|A x|_2}{|x|_2} = \mathrm{max}_i \sigma_i, $$
the largest singular value of $A$.

$$ \|A\|_F = |\boldsymbol{\sigma}|_2 \leq |\boldsymbol{\sigma}|_\infty = \|A\|_2$$